# If $p \mid a^{n}$ Prove that $p^{n} \mid a^{n}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, divisibility

$p$ Is a prime number.
I’ve found this problem in a math book.

My Proof :

We know that :$$p\mid n_{1}n_{2}…n_{i} \implies \exists j (1\le j \le i)$$such that $p/n_j $

So:
$$p \mid a^{n} \implies p\mid a \implies p^{n} \mid a^{n}$$
Please tell whether there is any mistake in my proof.

Comment: This is correct

Comment: Correct. You noticed the key (that we can conclude $p\mid a$). That means that there is an integer $k$ with $k\cdot p=a$ implying $k^n\cdot p^n=a^n$ hence $p^n\mid a^n$

Comment: The thing you know$$p\mid n_{1}n_{2}…n_{i} \implies p|n_j , 1\le j \le i$$is written in a misleading way.  Instead write$$p\mid n_{1}n_{2}…n_{i} \quad\implies\quad \exists j\; (1\le j \le i  \text{ and } p|n_j)$$

Comment: @GEdgar I will correct it

Comment: I think you should change $p|a\iff p^n|a^n$ to $p|a\implies p^n|a^n$, which is a clearer  presentation of what you wish to prove, even though the r-to-l implication is also true.

Comment: BTW I prefer \iff to \Leftrightarrow... (less typing!)... I always forget that p \mid n looks better than p|n when formatted.... I dk whether you know that you can type p^n instead of p^{n}. Some people prefer the latter as they say it makes their code easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

To prove the implication we need to prove that $a$ multiple of $p$ ,and $p$ is a prime number meaning
$PGCD(a.p)\neq 1$ 
Assume.  $PGCD(a.p)=1$ 
$(1)$...  $p\mid a^n=aa^{n-1} \wedge PGCD(a.p)=1 \Rightarrow p\mid a^{n-1} $ .... 
$(2)$....   $p\mid a^{n-1}=aa^{n-2}  \wedge PGCD(a.p)=1 \Rightarrow p\mid a^{n-2} $  
.
.
$(n-1)$..  $p\mid a^2=a.a \wedge PGCD(a.p)=1 \Rightarrow p\mid a $ 
This is a contradiction to the assumption above 
So $PGCD(a.p)\neq 1 \wedge p$ is a prime number we find 
$ (a=kp) ,   k\in\mathbb N^{*} $ 
Finally :
$ a^n= k^n.p^n \Leftrightarrow p^n\mid a^n $

Comment: what is PGCD? Do you mean gcd